# Получить доступ к Vue-компоненту внутри хука beforeRouteUpdate, Vue-router

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Необходимо отслеживать переход по динамическому маршруту. Например с '/course/lesson1' на '/course/lesson2'. Это можно сделать с помощью хука beforeRouteUpdate. Но в данном хуке нет доступа к Vue-компоненту. Такой доступ есть в хуке beforeRouteEnter, который не будет срабатывать при переходе '/course/lesson1' -> '/course/lesson2'. Есть ли возможность получить доступ к Vue-компоненту именно в хуке beforeRouteUpdate?

Мне это нужно, чтобы разрешить доступ для одних маршрутов /course/lesson:id и запретить для других подобных маршрутов.

LessonsList.vue

```
<template>
    <section>
    <ul>
        <router-link v-for="(lesson,index) in lessons"
                     v-bind:key="index"
                     :to="{
                        name: 'lesson',
                        params: {
                            id: index+1
                        }
                     }"
                     tag="li">

        </router-link>
    </ul>
        <router-view></router-view>
    </section>
</template>


import {mapGetters}     from 'vuex'

export default {
        computed: {
            ...mapGetters('course', {
                lessons: 'lessons'
            })
        },
        //Сработает для хука beforeRouteEnter, но не для beforeRouteUpdate
        beforeRouteEnter: (to,from,next) => {
            next(vm => console.log(vm.lessons));
        }
```

routes.js

```
 {
       name: 'course',
       path: '/course',
       component: LessonsList,
       children: [
             {name: 'lesson', path: 'lesson:id', component: Lesson}
       ]
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

В хуке beforeRouteUpdate уже есть доступ к Vue-компоненту без всяких колбэков, но нужно использовать не стрелочную ф-ю, а обычную. Тк. стрелочная не имеет собственного контекста.

```
 beforeRouteUpdate(to,from,next) {
            console.log(this.lessons);  //Работает
            next();
 }
```